# Relevance of file explore in DDMS android

Tags: android, ddms

hi
 i'm new to android. i have one simple doubt. when we run any application the ddms window shows the file explorer containing data, mnt and system folders. what is it? they have any physical existence in the system? and how can we get its content? pls answer my question... TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course File explorer has relevance you will notice when you will have to save some data on file system

> and how can we get its content?

show the attached image that is how you will do it.

[image]

**Note :** You can get or put contents of all the foders it all depends on permissions.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer.I have small doubt, can we pull or push the file using code?

Comment: let me explain. in my app i download a epub file and it `ll be downloaded to sdcard-download folder. i need to access the file through code and i need to present it in my ebook reader app(now i'm developing). how can it possible?

Comment: That typo mistake BTW check following link http://www.androidpeople.com/category/file-handling/ and check what suits you